# In Visual Studio is there a way to set a breakpoint in some function called via GetModuleHandle + GetProcAddress?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

When using the following code, it seems that even if I linked `TheFST.dll` with debug information (`/DEBUG`), I am unable to stop in a breakpoint in the function `setSecurityRetriever`.

Is there a reason for the .pdb not being loaded by VS when calling GetModuleHandle ? If it is normal, how can I change the behaviour to force VS to load the .pdb file ?

```
const string bondDataRetrieveDLLName("TheFST.dll");
HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle(bondDataRetrieveDLLName.c_str());
if(hMod)
{
    SecurityData bdrs = reinterpret_cast<SecurityData>(GetProcAddress(hMod, "setSecurityRetriever"));
    if(bdrs)
        bdrs(callback);
}
```

Comment: Did you compile the code files in TheFST.dll with `/Zi`. There there is no compiler option `/DEBUG`. `/DEBUG` is a linker option.

Comment: Silly me, you are right /Zi was not enabled, let me check and close the question if that works.

Comment: FWIW, using LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() allows setting breakpoints or at least stepping through the code with VC8. Further, if VS is still uncooperative, you can use DebugBreak() to trigger a break.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmaticaly set a breakpoint with DebugBreak(), as it was already mentioned.

You could also put __asm int 3 in where you want your breakpoint if you are using MSVC.
It will break exactly in that line. Just remember to remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Promoted from comments.

Did you compile the code files in TheFST.dll with `/Zi`? There there is no compiler option `/DEBUG`. `/DEBUG` is a linker option